# Dialog transition animation in listview

Tags: android, animation, transition

I need to makean animation on dialog like when user clicks on any item of list view , a pop up should open from that list position and should expand to full screen and similarly when user closes the dialog it should shrink down to the position it was clicked !
i have tried many examples but none worked for me !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer this [link](https://android.jlelse.eu/custom-dialog-with-circular-reveal-animation-ef7dc77ba1e) for creating `Custom Dialog` with `animation` effect. Also you can make use of `android transition` refer [here](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity).
For each list view item click you can open up this `dialog` from the adapter `click event`

Comment: I have checked these links , they have used animation that starts from bottom , what i need is dialog opens from a list view

Comment: if not dialog is there any other way to make a view visible with this kinda of animation